# Calling a method from one thread to another to execute in the other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, mysql-connector

I'm making a server in java that has a MySQL connection in another thread, so that it's event driven and won't block the main thread.

So far it works well, it works great for queries that don't return (insert, etc) but I'm not sure how to implement a callback method that will run in the other thread. If I simply call a method from the database connection thread, that method is run in that thread.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a queue of Runnables and let the non connection thread pick and run from that queue?

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm fairly new to multithreading, can you explain what "pick and run" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`.

If not, perhaps your DB thread could implement a command/query pool and for each command/query be able to call a given object's callback method using reflection. This will allow non-blocking command queueing and notification on command/query completion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [java.util.concurrent.Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and hand this to an object that will deal with the result

Answer (score 1):

One mechanism is to have a Queue ([ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)) of [FutureTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) instances. Your application thread would add instances to the Queue and then poll the tasks for completeness. Your database connection thread would poll the queue for tasks to service.

Answer (score 0):

A call back is usually executed in another thread. If you want to call something in the calling thread I would use an ExecutorService with a Future object. If you don't care which thread does the work, I would call it in the thread which does the DB query or add the task to another thread pool.

Here are some examples of using ExecutorServices

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html